How was Earth-10005's verse saved in the Deadpool & Wolverine?
Context
In the movie Deadpool & Wolverine, Universe-10005 is dying because Wolverine dies, he being the anchor being and all, and the whole story revolves around Deadpool trying to fix that.
So, Paradox shows the following to Deadpool at his TVA office:

This is supposed to show that 10005 is dying. Then, at the end of the film, B-15 shows the following to Wolverine and Deadpool:

Which shows that 10005 is regenerating.
Question
My question is, who really saves the verse, the apparent courageous effort of Wolverine and Deadpool (where neither died, hence no real sacrifice), or was it,
God of Stories, LOKI?
Remember this scene from Loki season-2 finale?


Could it be, that Loki saved this verse?

Do you have any reason to think that Loki's actions had anything to do with the film's events?

Well, for one, the TVA had no control or understanding of either the decay of verse-10005 or its regeneration. To them it was miraculous, magical. Also, when Paradox first introduces himself to DP, he talks about the sacred timeline, clearly proving that point existed in time before the Loki S2 finale.

"the TVA had no control or understanding of the decay of verse-10005" - that's clearly not true, they knew exactly why it was decaying and explained it very clearly to Deadpool.

Well, according to the movie's logic, verse-10005 just got new "anchor being", whether it was another Wolverine, or maybe even Deadpool himself.
